# onFinishRender not being fired

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HG52dgInXkumOA55G1bI?p=preview)

I'm loading data into a table using `ng-repeat`.

There is an `onFinishRender`, which emits `ngRepeatFinished`. However it's not being fired.

Any ideas why it's not working?

```
logsmgr.directive('onFinishRender', function ($timeout) {
    showLog("onFinishRender");
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            if (scope.$last === true) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    scope.$emit('ngRepeatFinished');
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you forget to add the directive to one of your elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the directive to one of your repeat elements. For example, from your Plunker add `on-finish-render`.

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in model.DataList" on-finish-render>
```

Comment: Yes, that fixed it!  

Thanks    

updated [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HG52dgInXkumOA55G1bI?p=preview)